# Build and publish multi-arch Docker container in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, azure-container-registry

I have used the default template of Visual Studio 2019 for a Blazor Server web application and enabled the Docker support for the project. It runs fine and I am also able to publish the Docker container to my own Azure Container registry via the "Publish" menu of VS2019.

Since I want to also publish an ARMv7 version of the image, I added another publish configuration that publishes to the tag "latest-arm", but to do this it is also necessary to change the base image in the "Dockerfile" to "aspnet:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7".

Do you have an idea if it is possible to change or add another Dockerfile with the base image for the ARM system? Any idea if it is possible to build and publish a multi-arch container that contains AMD64 and ARM support via the "Publish" command?

Comment: To change the base image, you need to update the Dockerfile. What's else do you expect?

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your answer. In my opinion it should be possible to select the Dockerfile that shall be used if I use the publish function of Visual Studio, because I am also able to select the platform under the publish options as well. Since the base ASP.NET image is a multi-arch image, there might also be away to build a multi-arch image with VS, too. However, I have not found a solution for any of those ways.

Comment: I think the VS create the image just by finding the file Dockerfile from the current folder.